# MultiThread handling and stopping midway

Tags: java, multithreading

i'm having trouble stopping a thread in the middle. This is part of my code, in the `StoplightThread` class I have problems on the first if statement. What it is supposed to do is wait at least 10 secs then allow the user to press the button so they can change the light, if the button is pressed it should stop the running thread in this case `Thread.sleep(40000)`. What happens is when I press the button it changes the light but does not stop the thread. If I press the button while there is still 20secs left it will add 20secs to the 10secs for the yellow light, making it yellow for 30 secs.

Edit: if you are wondering, `stoplightCanvas.x == 3` is green, `stoplightCanvas.x == 2` is yellow, and `stoplightCanvas.x == 1` is red.

```
class StoplightCanvas extends Canvas implements ActionListener
{  

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource() == cross) {
            isPressed = true;
            if (x == 3 && canCross)
                x = 2;     
        }
        repaint();
    }

}


class StoplightThread extends Thread
{
    StoplightCanvas stoplightCanvas;

    StoplightThread(StoplightCanvas stoplightCanvas) {
        this.stoplightCanvas = stoplightCanvas;
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        if (stoplightCanvas.x == 3){
               Thread.sleep(10000);
               stoplightCanvas.canCross = true;
               Thread.sleep(40000);
               if(stoplightCanvas.isPressed)
                   StoplightThread.interrupt();
           } else if (stoplightCanvas.x == 2) {
               Thread.sleep(10000);    
           } else if (stoplightCanvas.x == 1) {
               Thread.sleep(60000);
           }
       } catch (InterruptedException e){}

           stoplightCanvas.toggleColor();
           stoplightCanvas.repaint();
        }           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is written, the thread is sleeping for 40 seconds; then wakes up and checks for `stoplightCanvas.isPressed` and sets the interrupt flag...

If you want to interrupt the thread while it's sleeping, you need to interrupt from another thread. The EventDispatchThread is a fine place to do that, so you can either modify your current ActionListener, or create another one that does it.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        ...
        stopLightThread.interrupt();
    }
```

If you don't want to expose the button outside stopLightCanvas, then you can roll your own listener support in StopLightCanvas:

```
class StopLightCanvas extends Canvas implements ActionEventListener {
   public static interface StopLightListener extends EventListener {
     public void stopLightChanged(int state);
   }

   // watch out, you may need this to be threadsafe depending on your usage
   List<ActionEventListener> myListeners = new LinkedList<StopLightListener>();
   public void addStopLightListener(StopLightListener lst) {
     myListeners.add(lst);
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == cross) {
            isPressed = true;
            if (x == 3 && canCross)
                x = 2;     
        }
        repaint();

        for(StopLightListener lst: myListeners) {
           lst.stopLightChanged(x);
        }
   }

   ...
}

public class StopLightThread extends Thread implements {
    StoplightThread(StoplightCanvas stoplightCanvas) {
        this.stoplightCanvas = stoplightCanvas;
        stopLightCanvas.addStopLightListener(this);
    }

    ...

    @Override public void stopLightChanged(int state) {
        this.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Comment: I first see if the button is pressed, then try to do `StoplightThread.interrupt();`

Comment: When I try to do `StoplightThread.interrupt();` i get this error: `non-static method interrupt() cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: You are extending from the thread class yes? Have you read about the "this" and "super" keywords?

Comment: Yes, where would I use those?

Comment: what is `for(StopLightListener lst: myListeners)`, I do not think I have learned it yet.

Comment: @FJam shortcut way of saying iterate over all the listeners